# Edit Form in a Modal with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, renderpartial, nested-resources

In my `SCREEN` show view i render the comments

```
<%= render @screen.comments.order("created_at DESC") %>
```

that partial contains the comment AND an Edit Link which points to a modal which is also in that partial.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", '#EditComment', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>
```

The modal looks like this:

```
<!-- Comment Edit Modal -->
<% if can? :update, Comment %>
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditComment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog edit_scr_modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit your Comment</h4>
          </div>
          <%= form_for [@screen, comment] do |f| %>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form descr_area">
                <label>Comment:</label><br>
                <%= f.text_area :body, :rows => "3" %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn") do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Edit Comment
              <% end %>
            </div>

          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the Problem..

Although the Html outputted by this is targeting 2 different Comment ID's(2 Different Comments):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/s/7-testing-one-two-three/comments/20" class="edit_comment" id="edit_comment_20" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="0wcpual8qoJ1lzktwbNFPRikq/Cq4WCnyXi8IjIDitc=" />
</div>
```

and

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/s/7-testing-one-two-three/comments/11" class="edit_comment" id="edit_comment_11" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="0wcpual8qoJ1lzktwbNFPRikq/Cq4WCnyXi8IjIDitc=" />
</div>
```

Upon clicking the Edit link it Displays the Modal with the most recent comment(created_at DESC), if i click on another comment it just shows the first one again.

If i create a new comment, it will be again on all modals.

So i think it has something to do with the partial rendering when passing the .order(created_at DESC)...

What am i missing here??

**Routes:**

```rb
  resources :screens, :path => 's' do
    resources :comments
  end
```

**CommentsController:**

```rb
  def edit
    @screen = Screen.find(params[:screen_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @screen = Screen.find(params[:screen_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.screen_id = @screen.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user, recipient: @comment.screen.user
        format.html { redirect_to @screen, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @screen }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment.screen, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @screen }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending all the edit links to HTML element with `id = EditComment`. All your modals have the same `id` i.e., `EditComment`. So, It will always pick the first modal as that would be the first match.

You would need to change the main `div` of modal to have different `id's` for different `comments`. For example:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditComment_<%= comment.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

And then update your `link` as below,

```
<%= link_to "Edit", "#EditComment_#{comment.id}", 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>
```

Comment: Oh god... It's so logical now that you point it out :) Thanks Kirti.

Comment: Glad to help you again :D